# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument in subprocess

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

Python 3.3.3
Windows 7

```
Here is the full stack:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Blah\MyScript.py", line 578, in Call
    output = process.communicate( input=SPACE_KEY, timeout=600 )
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 928, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1202, in _communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The code looks like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen( arguments,
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                universal_newlines=True,
                env=environment )

output = process.communicate( input=SPACE_KEY, timeout=600 )
```

This code runs hundreds of times a day without problems.  But if more than one script is running on the same machine (the same script, but sometimes from different folders) I get the error.  The scripts are not executing the same thing (i.e.: the other script is not executing a subprocess when I get this error).

The subProcess code raises the error with many different command lines fed to it.

So, anyone has an idea as to what is happening?  Does the interpreter have a problem with multiple execution (in different processes)?
Same code that normally works perfectly fine, craps out if the interpreter is running the same (or very similar) scripts.  But they are usually executing different parts of the script.

I'm at a loss:  Using a single processor on an 8 core machine is annoying.

Comment: What OS are you running? It looks like windows but since this seems to be environmental you should include that in your question.

Comment: check that there is no filenames conflicts i.e., the scripts do not compete for the same resources. Do you start multiple subprocesses from the same Python script? Do you use `threading` module? Try to [create a minimal complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demostrates your issue

Comment: Yes, this is Windows 7.  There is no file conflicts (e.g.: two of the failing commands are SUBST and REG ADD which take no file, and the other running script don't do).  No resource competition with exclusive lock.  No multiple subprocesses per scripts.  No threading module.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem, but one more piece of info: That script (causing the errors) is actually run from a subprocess (synchronously).  While the others are not.  And all scripts start subprocesses of their own (all synchronous).

Comment: Are you still getting this problem? I've seen the same message in a script that calls multiple subprocesses.

Answer (score 9):

Previously `communicate` only ignored an `EPIPE` error when writing to the process `stdin`. Starting with 3.3.5, per [issue 19612](http://bugs.python.org/issue19612), it also ignores `EINVAL` (22) if the child has already exited (see [Lib/subprocess.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/62cf4e77f785/Lib/subprocess.py#l1173) line 1199).

**Background:**

`process.communiciate` calls `process.stdin.write`, which calls `io.FileIO.write`, which on Windows calls the C runtime [`_write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1570wh78%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which calls Win32 [`WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which in this case calls [`NtWriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which dispatches to the NamedPipe filesystem, as either an `IRP_MJ_WRITE` or `FastIoWrite`).

If the latter fails, it sets a Windows [system error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the thread. In this case the underlying Windows error is probably [`ERROR_NO_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_NO_DATA) (232) because the child process has already exited. The C runtime maps this to an `errno` value of `EINVAL` (22). Then since `_write` failed, `FileIO.write` raises `OSError` based on the current value of `errno`.

---

**Addendum:**

There wouldn't have been a problem at all if the CRT instead mapped `ERROR_NO_DATA` to `EPIPE`. Python's own Windows error translation generally follows the CRT's, but per [issue 13063](http://bugs.python.org/issue13063), it makes an exception to map `ERROR_NO_DATA` to `EPIPE` (32). Thus if the child has already exited, `_winapi.WriteFile` raises `BrokenPipeError`.

The following example replicates the `EINVAL` error given the child process has already exited. It also shows how [`_winapi.WriteFile`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/Modules/_winapi.c#l1139) (3.3.3 source link) would instead map this error to `EPIPE`. IMO, this should be considered a bug in Microsoft's CRT.

```
>>> cmd = 'reg query hkcu'                                                
>>> process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
>>> process.stdin.write(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

>>> hstdin = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(process.stdin.fileno())
>>> _winapi.WriteFile(hstdin, b' ')                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
```

Comment: +1 for the [EINVAL issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue19612). Issue 13063 seems unrelated -- is `winerror_to_errno()` called in this case? I don't see that `process.stdin.write()` uses `WriteFile()`. `FileIO.write()` calls `write(2)` (even on Windows) -- Is `write(2)` implemented via `WriteFile` on Windows?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, in the first paragraph I say that `FileIO.write` raises based on `errno`, so of course it's not using Python's Windows error translation. The 2nd paragraph and example show what the subprocess module would *want* the C runtime to set for `errno` in this case such that `communicate` would see an `EPIPE` error, which it was *already* designed to ignore. Instead the solution for issue 19612 introduced special handling for `EINVAL` that checks whether the child process has exited.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, the C runtime `_write` does call `WriteFile` in this case and translates the resulting `ERROR_NO_DATA` to an `EINVAL` `errno`. If the file descriptor were in a Unicode mode for a console handle, `_write` would instead call `WriteConsoleW`. Python 3's io module doesn't handle `_O_U16TEXT` mode well, anyway, because `FileIO` doesn't ensure writing in multiples of `sizeof(wchar_t)`, which causes the CRT to bugcheck.

Comment: Your 1st paragraph is not clear about what maps windows errors to errno. The 2nd paragraph talks about Python bug that changes how CPython maps windows errors to errno. It creates an impression that CPython maps the error in this case and issue 13063 could have converted the error to EPIPE -- it can't: Windows code sets errno to `22` in this case (Python has nothing to do with this value). It is clear from your comment that Windows and CPython translate ERROR_NO_DATA differently to EINVAL and EPIPE correspondingly and it justifies ignoring EINVAL in `.communicate()`.

Comment: Unicode + Windows console has nothing to do with this issue too. `subprocess` uses textio (`universal_newlines=True`) only if PIPE is used: no Windows console is involved.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, you're the one who asked whether `_write` calls `WriteFile`. It generally does, but I wanted to cover the case that it doesn't in my comment, and add some tangentially related information that I thought you may find interesting since I had previously talked to you about issue 1602.

Comment: exceptional depth. The docs say that `_write` should produce EINVAL if `buffer` is NULL but Python passes non-null `buffer` here (whether child process is alive can't change it) and `WriteFile` is documented to return `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` if the read end of the anonymous pipe is closed (if the child process ends; it probably closes its end) and `ERROR_NO_DATA` is not mentioned at all - it is not clear at what level this error occurs. Also, to confirm, `os.write(process.stdin.fileno(), b' ')` raises `EINVAL` on Windows instead of EPIPE in the last code example?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, from testing I confirm that `os.write` also raises  `EINVAL`. In posixmodule.c, it calls [`posix_error`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/Modules/posixmodule.c#l1197), which calls `PyErr_SetFromErrno`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, `WriteFile` sets the Win32 last error from the underlying [NT status code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx), which ultimately is up to what the filesystem sets in the `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`. A breakpoint on `ntdll!NtWriteFile` shows the status code is `STATUS_PIPE_CLOSING` (0xC00000B1). Via ctypes one can see that `windll.ntdll.RtlNtStatusToDosError(0xC00000B1) == 232`. Other error status codes for a disconnected pipe are `STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED` (Win32 `ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED`) and `STATUS_PIPE_LISTENING` (Win32 `ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I can only get `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` for reading from the `process.stdout` pipe. In this case, setting a breakpoint on `ntdll!NtReadFile` shows the status code is `STATUS_PIPE_BROKEN`. So I think the `WriteFile` docs are either disappointingly incomplete or just plain wrong. It looks like someone wrote that section of the docs and the corresponding section for [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the same time and didn't actually check that the error is different for `WriteFile`.

Answer (score 8):

@eryksun very well analyzed the core of the issue, but I think the bigger picture (the obvious things, probably) is missing in his answer.

***So, anyone has an idea as to what is happening?***

Your code suffers from a race condition. Sometimes your child process does not behave the way you think it behaves.

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` is raised in your case when the child exits *before* `communicate` attempts to write to the named pipe, which `subprocess` has established between your parent and stdin of your child process.

`Popen()` does a lot under the hood. In your case, it first creates three named pipes (in `_get_handles()`), via `_winapi.CreatePipe()`, one for each of stdin/out/err. Then, it spawns the child process (in `_execute_child()`), using `_winapi.CreateProcess()`.

`_execute_child()` finishes with cleanup procedures. Remember: all of this happens within `Popen()`.

Only after `Popen()` returns, your Python VM in the parent process is about to proceed with the invocation of `output = process.communicate(input=SPACE_KEY, timeout=600)`

Given that you are on a multi core system, your system has time slices available to let the child process do some work while your Python interpreter is still *within* execution of `Popen()`.

That is, there is **a narrow time window** between `_winapi.CreateProcess()` (after which the child process does some work) and Python's attempt to write to the child's stdin via `communicate()` (which makes a call to Windows' `WriteFile`, as eryksun nicely explained).

When your child exits in **that** time window you retrieve named error.

Why your child process exits earlier than expected? Only you can tell. Obviously, it does not *always* wait for data coming from stdin.

Comment: Frigg mentioned in a comment that it's starting programs such `reg.exe` that don't actually wait to read from stdin. I wouldn't have been able to reproduce the error otherwise, even with the relatively 'long' delay before calling `process.stdin.write(' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

The command (args) might be incorrect for OS that you're using. Try to sanitize them (check / pass through only allowed characters).

Comment: It works hundreds of times a day and args is not really dynamic, it is only a tuple so that the enclosing function can take the actual args.  There is no reason to sanitize, I have total control of the command in my script.