# Running interactive program from within python

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multithreading, rasa-nlu

I want to achieve something which is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python).

My actual goal is to run Rasa from within python.
Taken from Rasa's site:

> Rasa is a framework for building conversational software: Messenger/Slack bots, Alexa skills, etc. We’ll abbreviate this as a bot in this documentation.

It is basically a chatbot which runs in the command prompt. This is how it works on cmd : 
[image]

Now I want to run Rasa from python so that I can integrate it with my Django-based website. i.e. I want to keep taking inputs from the user, pass it to rasa, rasa processes the text and gives me an output which I show back to the user.

I have tried this (running it from cmd as of now)

```py
import sys
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty  # python 3.x


def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line)
    out.close()


def getOutput(outQueue):
    outStr = ''
    try:
        while True: #Adds output from the Queue until it is empty
            outStr+=outQueue.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        return outStr

p = subprocess.Popen('command_to_run_rasa', 
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    shell=False, 
                    universal_newlines=True,
                    )

outQueue = Queue()

outThread = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, outQueue))

outThread.daemon = True

outThread.start()

someInput = ""

while someInput != "stop":
    someInput = input("Input: ") # to take input from user
    p.stdin.write(someInput) # passing input to be processed by the rasa command
    p.stdin.flush()
    output = getOutput(outQueue)
    print("Output: " + output + "\n")
    p.stdout.flush()
```

But it works fine only for the first line of output. Not for successive input/output cycles. See output below.

[image]

How do I get it working for multiple cycles?
I've referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688492/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-in-subprocess), and I think I understand the problem in my code from it but I dont know how to solve it.

EDIT: I'm using Python 3.6.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10

Comment: Just use shell=True...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to keep interacting with your subprocess - at the moment once you pick the output from your subprocess you're pretty much done as you close its `STDOUT` stream.

Here is the most rudimentary way to continue user input -> process output cycle:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":  # a guard from unintended usage
    input_buffer = sys.stdin  # a buffer to get the user input from
    output_buffer = sys.stdout  # a buffer to write rasa's output to
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["path/to/rasa", "arg1", "arg2", "etc."],  # start the process
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  # pipe its STDIN so we can write to it
                            stdout=output_buffer, # pipe directly to the output_buffer
                            universal_newlines=True)
    while True:  # run a main loop
        time.sleep(0.5)  # give some time for `rasa` to forward its STDOUT
        print("Input: ", end="", file=output_buffer, flush=True)  # print the input prompt
        print(input_buffer.readline(), file=proc.stdin, flush=True)  # forward the user input
```

You can replace `input_buffer` with a buffer coming from your remote user(s) and `output_buffer` with a buffer that forwards the data to your user(s) and you'll get essentially what you're looking for - the sub-process will be getting the input directly from the user (`input_buffer`) and print its output to the user (`output_buffer`).

If you need to perform other tasks while all this is running in the background, just run everything under the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard in a separate thread, and I'd suggest adding a `try..except` block to pick up `KeyboardInterrupt` and exit gracefully.

But... soon enough you'll notice that it doesn't exactly work properly all the time - if it takes longer than half a second of wait for `rasa` to print its `STDOUT` and enter the *wait for `STDIN`* stage, the outputs will start to mix. This problem is considerably more complex than you might expect. The main issue is that `STDOUT` and `STDIN` (and `STDERR`) are separate buffers and you cannot know when a subprocess is actually expecting something on its `STDIN`. This means that without a clear indication from the subprocess (like you have the `\r\n[path]>` in Windows CMD prompt on its `STDOUT` for example) you can only send data to the subprocesses `STDIN` and hope it will be picked up.

Based on your screenshot, it doesn't really give a distinguishable `STDIN` request prompt because the first prompt is `... :\n` and then it waits for `STDIN`, but then once the command is sent it lists options without an indication of its end of `STDOUT` stream (technically making the prompt just `...\n` but that would match any line preceding it as well). Maybe you can be clever and read the `STDOUT` line by line, then on each new line measure how much time has passed since the sub-process wrote to it and once a threshold of inactivity is reached assume that `rasa` expects input and prompt the user for it. Something like:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import threading

# we'll be using a separate thread and a timed event to request the user input
def timed_user_input(timer, wait, buffer_in, buffer_out, buffer_target):
    while True:  # user input loop
        timer.wait(wait)  # wait for the specified time...
        if not timer.is_set():  # if the timer was not stopped/restarted...
            print("Input: ", end="", file=buffer_out, flush=True)  # print the input prompt
            print(buffer_in.readline(), file=buffer_target, flush=True)  # forward the input
        timer.clear()  # reset the 'timer' event

if __name__ == "__main__":  # a guard from unintended usage
    input_buffer = sys.stdin  # a buffer to get the user input from
    output_buffer = sys.stdout  # a buffer to write rasa's output to
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["path/to/rasa", "arg1", "arg2", "etc."],  # start the process
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  # pipe its STDIN so we can write to it
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # pipe its STDIN so we can process it
                            universal_newlines=True)
    # lets build a timer which will fire off if we don't reset it
    timer = threading.Event()  # a simple Event timer
    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=timed_user_input,
                                    args=(timer,  # pass the timer
                                          1.0,  # prompt after one second
                                          input_buffer, output_buffer, proc.stdin))
    input_thread.daemon = True  # no need to keep the input thread blocking...
    input_thread.start()  # start the timer thread
    # now we'll read the `rasa` STDOUT line by line, forward it to output_buffer and reset
    # the timer each time a new line is encountered
    for line in proc.stdout:
        output_buffer.write(line)  # forward the STDOUT line
        output_buffer.flush()  # flush the output buffer
        timer.set()  # reset the timer
```

You can use a similar technique to check for more complex 'expected user input' patterns. There is a whole module called [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) designed to deal with this type of tasks and I wholeheartedly recommend it if you're willing to give up some flexibility.

**Now**... all this being said, you are aware that [`Rasa`](http://rasa.com/) is built in Python, installs as a Python module and has a Python API, right? Since you're already using Python why would you call it as a subprocess and deal with all this `STDOUT/STDIN` shenanigans when you can directly run it from your Python code? Just import it and interact with it directly, they even have a very simple example that does exactly what you're trying to do: [Rasa Core with minimal Python](https://core.rasa.com/no_python.html#rasa-core-with-minimal-python).