# Script Terminates Abruptly with OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid Argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have written this code basically this code reads data from bot.txt and performs an operation the question is it breaks after running for a while I'm not sure what's wrong can anyone please point out what's actually wrong here please thanks

```
import subprocess
import re

# Read only 66-character hexadecimal values from bot.txt, excluding the last line
with open('bot.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()[:-1]  # Exclude the last line
    hex_values = [re.search(r'\b[0-9a-fA-F]{66}\b', line).group() for line in lines]

# Run keymath command for each pair of hex values in reverse order and save the output to output.txt
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for i in range(len(hex_values)-1, 0, -1):  # Start from the last key and go to the first key
        current_key = hex_values[i]
        next_key = hex_values[i - 1]  # Use the previous line as next_key

        # Flip the first character of current_key
        if current_key.startswith('02'):
            current_key = '03' + current_key[2:]
        elif current_key.startswith('03'):
            current_key = '02' + current_key[2:]

        # Run keymath command and capture the output
        command = ['./keymath', current_key, '-', next_key]
        print(f"Executing command: {' '.join(command)}")  # Print the command before executing
        result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        # Save the result to output.txt
        output_file.write(f"{result.stdout}\n")
```

the error that i get after a while is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rage/ecctools/auto.py", line 24, in <module>
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: './keymath'
```

not sure why it suddenly stops there about 20 million lines if data in bot.txt

Comment: This doesn't seem 100% a match, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688492/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-in-subprocess).